# Get the eng version of toLabel field value from SOQL

Tags: soql, static-resources

I have a field in soql which I have marked as tolabel(), the reason is to get the field value translated for the login user. But the same field value name is used in static resource to display the img. So when I add to label the url of the static resource dont work. If I remove the tolabel() then the translated don't work, both the process is handled by same field. I am working aura, and i want to avoid extra Soql if possible. Do anyone have any idea how to get the default value from the tolabel fields result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to query both the API Name and Value of a picklist field in the same SOQL Query.  This is possible, but you must use an alias.  For example, if you have a picklist field `Status__c` on the Account object, you can query like so:

```
Account account = [
    SELECT Id, Status__c, toLabel(Status__c) statusValue 
      FROM ACCOUNT 
     LIMIT 1
];
System.debug('Status__c API Name:' + account.Status__c);
System.debug('Status__c Value:' + (String)account.get('statusValue');
```

In the query, `statusValue` serves as an alias for `toLabal(Status__c)`, essentially giving it another name in the results, so you don't end up with two columns with the same name.  Also note that aliased fields cannot be accessed via dot notation (`account.statueValue` will not compile); you must instead use `sObject.get(fieldName)`, which returns an `Object`, so you will also need to cast the return value to a real type.